# Stripe charge customer on a specific date

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a booking system wherein we charge the customer twice. 1st is we charge them 25% upon reservation, then 2nd is the remaining 75% when the date is 7 days before the check in date.

Is this set up possible in stripe? I am not sure if i will implement it using subscription? If not subscription, is it possoble to charge the user on a specific date? I can always get the date of the 7 days before the check in date.

Any tips regarding the flow is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For one-off charges (not recurring), you need to make the API calls to create the charges at the time that you want them to happen. You can't schedule a single payment to occur at a specific time in Stripe directly. You could set this up as a cron job on your own server that makes the API calls, for example. Stripe Billing is more for recurring payments and wouldn't be a good fit.

Comment: @taintedzodiac is that possible that I set up a cron job that will execute a "one-off charge"? Given that i store the payment_method_id in my DB then I will trigger that one of charge? Shouldn't that require a user interaction for the payment to push through? Or there's no need already as long as I have a hold of their payment method? Thanks!

Comment: As long as you [setup the card](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment) with `setup_future_usage: "off_session"`when you collected it, you can pass `off_session: true` in your cron'd requests to make sure the user is (usually) not required to be present. You would of course want to handle any errors and bring the user back on later for any failed payments.